# How to create horizontal forms with twitter bootstrap and rails simple form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am trying to create horizontal forms with simple-form and bootstrap. I have already installed bootstrap using "rails generate simple_form:install". This is what i have in html.erb

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@company, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <%= f.input :name %>
</div>
</div>
```

But the form still appears vertically.

Comment: Which of the 2 major Bootstrap versions are you using? (they are very different)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

simple_form is a really great gem for generating bootstrap forms. However, you have to do a little extra to get it working with Bootstrap’s **form-horizontal** class.

The README doesn’t mention this, but it’s built in. Just write your form declaration like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @c], html: { class: 'form-horizontal' },wrapper: :horizontal_form do |f| %>

 # ...form...

<% end %>
```

Note the **wrapper** attribute. This isn’t described in the README, and I had to dig through the code to figure it out.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: do you know how i can enlarge the input size to medium size? giving the code  above

Comment: Here is the official example with the source code: http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/examples/horizontal