# Display a form horizontally using form_for, Ruby on Rails, twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Following a Ruby on Rails tutorial and the code given below is supposed to display a form horizontally.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= form_for(@recipe, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">
          <%= f.label :name %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Name of recipe", autofocus: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it still displays the form vertically. I have tried this answer with `wrapper` snippet but still doesn't work: [How to create horizontal forms with twitter bootstrap and rails simple form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422959/how-to-create-horizontal-forms-with-twitter-bootstrap-and-rails-simple-form).

I have read from this link: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html, that `form_for` is now soft-deprecated. Is that why? And if so how can I use form_with to achieve the same result.

Comparison:
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWsGS.png)
vs [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaET1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the sample for your case

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= form_for(@recipe, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
      <div class="row form-group">
        <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Name of recipe", autofocus: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```